# WPF: Auto truncating text in TextBlock

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a TextBlock of Width 600 and Height 80 in my WPF 4.0 application. I would like to truncate text and append ***...*** at the end, at runtime.

How can I approach it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Is it a TextBox or TextBlock?

If it is TextBlock, then you can use:

**In C#**:

```
myTextBlock.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis;
```

OR

**In XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Name="myTextBlock" Margin="20" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
  TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
  FontSize="14"
>
```

But if it were a TextBox, then as per my knowledge, you can bind a `ValueConverter` to the textbox and return the trancated text(with dots : ...) into the text box but save the full text into the `Tag` property of the textbox. So that your original text is not lost.

But, as per my knowledge, it is not a good practice to apply text trimming on text boxes until there is a specific requirement.

Comment: Is there a way I can wrap the text without setting width of the TextBlock?

Comment: The wrapping of text inside a control is based on the width of that control. If you want to implement the wrapping irrespective of width,then ValueConverter is the easiest option you can pick, as per my knowledge.