# Adding 3 dots at end of text if textblock doesn't have enough width

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In a windows 8.1 project i have a textblock in my xaml

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" Text="{Binding Item.Name}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

This textblock is inside a grid with 350 width.
Sometimes the text bound to the texblock has many words and because of that the textblock doesn't show all of it.

I would like to know if there is a way to add `"..."` at the end of the text to give the user the ideia that there is more text.

Comment: Did you try searching? [`TextTrimming`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.texttrimming) is what you're looking for, see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745577/wpf-auto-truncating-text-in-textblock) (also applies to Windows Apps).

Comment: ah ok, was confusing with TextWrapping, thanks